# Temporarily disable key input java

Tags: java, user-interface, keyboard

I am currently working on a basic game that uses Timers with JProgressBars to add a filling effect for character stats. One problem I run into is that if another character is selected before the progress bars are filled, it causes the graphics to overlap and look very buggy. The timers are connected to JButtons via a custom action class, and the buttons can be navigated via keys. What I want to do is disable key input when the action begins, and re-enable keys when the longest timer finishes. If code is helpful ask and I will upload the file. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I know I am not helping, but Swing wasn't designed for games.

Comment: Swing is just used for menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any code its difficult to find out any fix. However if your timers are Threads, maybe a Thread Group would be useful. How about this:

```
public class MyWindow {
    Integer numTimersRunning = 0;
    ...
    {
            // timer started here
            numTimersRunning++;
            //timer does its thing and makes the progress bars go up.
            ...
            //timer finishes
            numTimersRunning--;
    }

    void keyPressed(MouseEvent e) {
     if(numTimersRunning > 0) 
              return;
     // do your keyboard input processing....
    }
}
```

I dunno just a shot in the dark, good luck.

ps: sounds like you might be encoutering some double buffering issued. check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html